# iOS "copy" keyword on Mutable objects

Tags: ios

I've a theoretical doubt about two type of declaration of a mutable object in iOS (and MacOSX I think) with ARC.

What's the difference between a declaration of an NSMutableArray in the Class Extension, like the code below:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (copy) NSMutableArray* myMutableArray;

@end 

//Class implementation
@implementation MyViewController
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _myMutableArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
}
```

and a declaration of the same array in this way

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* myMutableArray;

@end 

//Class implementation
@implementation MyViewController
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _myMutableArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
}
```

Which one is better? I've seen both versions around and apparently both work fine. However I'd like to know which one is the best option.
I know that the "copy" keyword is to use copy for classes that are part of a class cluster that have mutable/immutable pairs. So in this case, it appear to be the right choice. But the use of the "copy" keyword and the "mutableCopy" property (like the first example) seems a duplicate to me. Am I wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The strong property is the one to use. Since its a mutable object (and is declared as such) then you wouldn't want a copy making, since then things like `[self.myArray addObject:object]` wouldn't work. You'd use `copy` properties for immutable objects that may have mutable versions passed in (so an NSString would often be a copy property).

The way the arrays are assigned (making a mutable copy of an empty array made using objective-c literals) is pretty clumsy and would be better written as `self.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Also, don't access the instance variable directly, use the property accessor.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, with the introduction of literals, I saw often a declaration like this: 
`self.myMutableArray = [@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"] mutableCopy];`

Comment: Right, since the literal is immutable this creates a mutable copy of it.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense for a literal array with something in it, but not for an empty one.